# WP7 App: Too large page

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I have created a small WP7 app which contains one page which is dynamically filled with content. But it goes out of viewable area. Emulator doesn't scroll the page when I click-hold-move on the screen. How do I make it scroll when needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple option is to drop the content you require inside a `ScrollViewer`, so for example adding a large `TextBlock` as so:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="scrollViewer" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
    <TextBlock Height="30" Name="textBlock" FontSize="24"
               Text="This is a long block of text which wont fit in the available area" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Obviously, in most cases you will want to drop a container control such as `Grid` or `StackPanel` into the `ScrollViewer` and place all your other controls in there.

That said, I'm wondering if you are actually looking for some of the standard WP7 Metro look and feel controls such as the [Panorama and Pivot Controls](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/09/phone-tools-toolkit-and-more-released/) which are available in the latest dev tools - follow that link for full details.